# Unable to click the button using querySelector in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Have dynamic page, here I need to click one button. So tried below code, but it is not working and not giving any alert. But if we use the same in code browser console, it is executing and giving alert. Kindly suggest me how to resolve this,

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    document.querySelector('.test-class')?.addEventListener('click', event => {
      alert(event);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Most likely means that document.querySelector did not find the element, because it did not exist at that point.

Comment: Exactly, please do add your `html` code, that we can dig a bit further to help you find the solution.

Comment: You said you're trying to click the button, but the code attached only *listens* to a click even from a certain element. Can you please add more context and code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to use the `document` inside angular, but in common it would be better to avoid it and use instead `Renderer2.listen()`, which is a more safe way to do custom rendering things.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).